# django custom user can't set attribute error

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-registration, django-custom-user

I followed  CodingEntrepreneurs tutorial on Custom Users and extended it to have 3 types of users: school, parent and vendor.
I have created view, form for each type of user.
In **forms.py** I have

```
class ParentSignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('email', )

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(ParentSignUpForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        
        if commit:
            user.is_parent = True
            user.save()
        return user
```

I try to change **is_parent** attribute from **False** to **True**. However, error is:

```
  File "/home/azamat/dev/dj_test/src/accounts/forms.py", line 137, in save
    user.is_parent = True
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

How to solve this issue? Or any better way to save users with different types?

UPDATE:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
)



class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, is_staff=False, is_admin=False, is_active=True, is_parent=False, is_school=False, is_vendor=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a password")

        user_obj = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password) # change user password
        user_obj.parent = is_parent
        user_obj.school = is_school
        user_obj.vendor = is_vendor
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_parentuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
                email,
                password=password,
                is_parent=True
        )
        return user

    def create_schooluser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
                email,
                password=password,
                is_school=True
        )
        return user

    def create_vendoruser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
                email,
                password=password,
                is_vendor=True
        )
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
                email,
                password=password,
                is_staff=True
        )
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
                email,
                password=password,
                is_staff=True,
                is_admin=True,
        )
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email       = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    active      = models.BooleanField(default=True) # can login 
    parent      = models.BooleanField(default=False) # parent user
    school      = models.BooleanField(default=False) # school admin user
    vendor      = models.BooleanField(default=False) # vendor user  
    staff       = models.BooleanField(default=False) # staff user non superuser
    admin       = models.BooleanField(default=False) # superuser 
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' #username

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_parent(self):
        return self.parent

    @property
    def is_school(self):
        return self.school
        
    @property
    def is_vendor(self):
        return self.is_vendor

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin
```

Comment: Can you post your user model?

Answer (score 0):

How I solved it:

I have added **REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['parent', 'school', 'vendor' ]** to my **model.py** So now on my registration page, I have 3 check buttons where I can select a needed type of user.

In **forms.py** I left only **RegisterForm** and deleted register forms for my 3 user types

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', **'parent', 'school', 'vendor'**) #'added 3 fields',)

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        # user.active = False # send confirmation email
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```